# How to theme Angular Material using Material Theme Builder

Tags: css, sass, angular-material

I created a theme using the [Material Theme Builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom) which I later exported to .css
I got a bunch of different files that I don't know how to connect to Angular Material or how to use them as my own custom theme.

Here is the files that I got. I cut some content of them, as to not clutter the question.

**colors.module.css**

```
.primary {
  background-color: var(--md-sys-color-primary);
}
.primary-text {
  color: var(--md-sys-color-primary);
}
.on-primary {
  background-color: var(--md-sys-color-on-primary);
}
.on-primary-text {
  color: var(--md-sys-color-on-primary);
}
```

**theme.css**

```
@import url(tokens.css);
@import url(colors.module.css);
@import url(typography.module.css);
@import url(theme.light.css) (prefers-color-scheme: light);
@import url(theme.dark.css) (prefers-color-scheme: dark);
```

**theme.dark.css**

```
:root {
 --md-sys-color-primary: var(--md-sys-color-primary-dark);
 --md-sys-color-on-primary: var(--md-sys-color-on-primary-dark);
 --md-sys-color-primary-container: var(--md-sys-color-primary-container-dark);
 --md-sys-color-on-primary-container: var(--md-sys-color-on-primary-container-dark);
 --md-sys-color-secondary: var(--md-sys-color-secondary-dark);
 --md-sys-color-on-secondary: var(--md-sys-color-on-secondary-dark);
 --md-sys-color-secondary-container: var(--md-sys-color-secondary-container-dark);
 --md-sys-color-on-secondary-container: var(--md-sys-color-on-secondary-container-dark);
 --md-sys-color-tertiary: var(--md-sys-color-tertiary-dark);
}
```

**theme.light.css**

```
:root {
 --md-sys-color-primary: var(--md-sys-color-primary-light);
 --md-sys-color-on-primary: var(--md-sys-color-on-primary-light);
 --md-sys-color-primary-container: var(--md-sys-color-primary-container-light);
 --md-sys-color-on-primary-container: var(--md-sys-color-on-primary-container-light);
 --md-sys-color-secondary: var(--md-sys-color-secondary-light);
 --md-sys-color-on-secondary: var(--md-sys-color-on-secondary-light);
 --md-sys-color-secondary-container: var(--md-sys-color-secondary-container-light);
 --md-sys-color-on-secondary-container: var(--md-sys-color-on-secondary-container-light);
 --md-sys-color-tertiary: var(--md-sys-color-tertiary-light);
}
```

**tokens.css**

```
:root {
  --md-source: #141616;
  /* primary */
  --md-ref-palette-primary0: #000000;
  --md-ref-palette-primary10: #002021;
  --md-ref-palette-primary20: #003738;
  --md-ref-palette-primary25: #004345;
  --md-ref-palette-primary30: #004f52;
  --md-ref-palette-primary35: #005c5f;
  --md-ref-palette-primary40: #00696c;
  --md-ref-palette-primary50: #008488;
  --md-ref-palette-primary60: #00a1a5;
  --md-ref-palette-primary70: #1dbdc2;
  --md-ref-palette-primary80: #4cd9de;
  --md-ref-palette-primary90: #6ff6fb;
  --md-ref-palette-primary95: #b9fdff;
  --md-ref-palette-primary98: #e4feff;
  --md-ref-palette-primary99: #f1ffff;
  --md-ref-palette-primary100: #ffffff;
}
```

**typography.module.css**

```
.display-large{
  font-family: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-font-family-name);
  font-style: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-font-family-style);
  font-weight: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-font-weight);
  font-size: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-font-size);
  letter-spacing: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-tracking);
  line-height: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-height);
  text-transform: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-text-transform);
  text-decoration: var(--md-sys-typescale-display-large-text-decoration);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme you created is a Material 3 theme, but as of now Angular Material is still using Material 2. According to https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22738, the transition to Material 3 is planned for Angular Material 17.1. A preview version is already available.